# C# Timer won't run down to form freezing

Tags: c#, forms, timer

so when i try and press "button 2" I expect two things to happen a)"dowsomething" is suppose to do its thing in the "now" class. b) Whilst its doing something i want it to count how long that something takes. However because "dosomething" is program hungry Form1 freezes and it wont run the timer. Im a bit of a rookie at c# so I wouldn't know how to run it in the background. So any outside the box ideas? Thanks.

```
     int time = 0;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            timer1.Start();
            nowthen now = new nowthen();
            now.dosomething(withthis); //This task is program hungry and causes the form to freeze
            timer1.Stop();
            time = 0;  
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time = time + 1;
        label2.Text = time.ToString();
        label2.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong in general. Go read about the Windows message queue and then perform the time consuming operation on another thread so that the UI can remain responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 4 use:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((Action) delegate()
{
    // this code is now executing on a new thread.
    nowthen now = new nowthen();
    now.dosomething(withthis);

    // to update the UI from here, you must use Invoke to make the call on UI thread
    textBox1.Invoke((Action) delegate()
    {
          textBox1.Text = "This update occurs on the UI thread";
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not simply `() =>` instead of `(Action)delegate()`?

Comment: This looks nice however Task is stating that "Task it does not exist in the current context" I am using .NET 4.

Comment: Absolutly beautiful exactly what I was looking for! Final question...How would I go about adding information to form1 textbox its basically saying a thread cant add info to a textbox?

Comment: This is because your new thread cannot access the textbox, you must marshall the update call back onto the UI thread (answer edited).

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Forms, all of your UI stuff runs on one thread. That includes the timer - the timer is implemented behind the scenes with windows messages.

Your question is actually two questions:-

1. How can I time an operation in C# / Windows forms?

How to time something depends on the precision you're looking for. For accuracy in the region of +/- 10ms then you can use Environment.TickCount - store it's value before your operation, then get the value again after, and subtract the stored value - and you have your duration.

More precise is the Stopwatch class in System.Threading - see http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

1. How can I run a task "in the background" ?

To run your operation in the background, you need to run it in a different thread. The easiest, designed friendly (but perhaps not all that flexible way) is to use the BackgroundWorker component. This wraps using a worker thread to do an operation for you. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker for a good explanation of how to do that.

More advanced, and more flexible, is to create your own thread to do the work. However, that will create some important issues to consider around how to syncronize what's going on - as soon as you start your thread, your method call finishes (it's asyncronous) and you need to have a mechanism for notifiying your UI code that the process has finished.  This example seems as good as any on how to create your own thread: http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/create-a-worker-thread-for-your-windows-form-in-csharp/

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to time how long something takes, use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
nowThen = new nowThen();
no.dosomething(withthis);
sw.Stop();
// you can get the time it took from sw.Elapsed
```

That won't, however, update a label with the elapsed time.

Comment: Won't see the timer counting down this way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll throw this in too, although it's not as elegant looking as @paul's solution.

```
timer1.Start();
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, e) => { now.dosomething((myArgumentType)e.Argument); };
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => { timer1.Stop(); };
bw.RunWorkerAsync(withthis);
```

This starts your timer, creates a new BackgroundWorker thread, tells it what to run in the `DoWork` method (dosomething runs in a separate thread), then stops the timer in the `RunWorkerCompleted` method (after dosomething is finished, control returns to the main thread in RunWorkerCompleted).